# Cutting image using gdalwarp to extent of data

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am currently generating a raster from point data and applying inverse distance algorithm.  This image is then cut with:

```
gdalwarp -cutline <<src shapefile>> -crop_to_cutline -srcnodata 0 results_in.tiff results_out.tiff
```

Is there a way to cut the output to the extremities of the original data source file rather than a shapefile?

EDIT : gdal_grid command

```
gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2:smoothing=0.001:radius1=0.0005:radius2=0.0005 -of GTiff -zField z_value -ot Float64 -l data VRT.vrt EM_RESULTS.tiff
```

Comment: So, I am unable to test this directly since I am on my iphone in a bus right now. I checked the gdalwarp documentaion, and it looks like the output extent is tied specifically to the cutline when you use the `-crop_to_cutline` option. I would try removing that option, which should cause it to default to the intersection of all input files. (in this case there is only the one input file so it should default to that) Give that a try and let me know what happens. If it does not solve your problem I will play with it tonight when I get home.

Comment: The data is extrapolated beyond the boundary prior to the GDALwarp so in hindsight the issue is perhaps with my gdalgrid command edited as above

Answer (score 4):

[`gdalwarp`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) utility has a target extent option:

> **-te xmin ymin xmax ymax:**
>       set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS).

Instead, [`gdal_grid`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) has two options, one for each axis:

> **-txe xmin xmax:**
>       Set georeferenced X extents of output file to be created.
>
> **-tye ymin ymax:**
>       Set georeferenced Y extents of output file to be created.

**EDIT**
So if you want to cut the interpolated raster with the boundary (and not the extent) of the region defined by your points, i.e. a convex (or concave) hull, you have to calculate it before. Actually, it's only possible to calculate the convex hull with GDAL > 1.10 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite support. In the next future (with SpatiaLite 4.0 support, GDAL 1.10.2?), it will be possible to calculate the concave hull too.

**Convex hull:**

```
ogr2ogr convex_hull.shp points.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geometry)) FROM points"
```

Finally, you can use `convex_hull.shp` as cutline in `gdalwarp` and so obtain the result.